How to store a large amount of data in an array or
I am trying to generate c-code for a large number of samples to be used in a microcontroller program. Because internal ram is limited I need to force the table into flash memory.
The code below is used to generate a .C source file.
The variables "first" and "last" have low values for the example but will eventually result in hundreds of sample lines.
    FILE *fp = stdout; // fopen("/home/hennep/arrays.c","w+");
    const int first=5, last=8;
    fprintf( fp, "const uint8_t samples[%d][] = { { ", last-first+1 );
    for( int j = first; j <= last; j++ ) {
        if( j != first ) {
            fprintf( fp, "                              , { ");
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
            uint8_t byt = sin( 3.141592654 * 360.0 * i / j / 180.0 ) * 127.5 + 127.5;
            if( i ) {
                fprintf( fp, ", %d", byt );
            } else {
                fprintf( fp, "%d", byt );
            }
        }
        fprintf( fp, " }\n" );
    }
    fprintf( fp, "                              };\n\n" );

Obviously this is not going to work because:
const uint8_t samples[4][] = { { 127, 248, 202, 52, 6 }
                             , { 127, 237, 237, 127, 17, 17 }
                             , { 127, 227, 251, 182, 72, 3, 27 }
                             , { 127, 217, 255, 217, 127, 37, 0, 37 }
                             };

note: declaration of 'samples' as multidimensional array must  
have bounds for all dimensions except the first  

I could rotate the matrix by 90 degrees clockwise, but for readability I prefer not to do that.
const uint8_t samples[][4] = { { 127, 127, 127, 127 }
                             , { 217, 227, 237, 248 }
                             , { 255, 251, 237, 202 }
                             , { 217, 182, 127, 52  }
                             , { 127, 72,  17,  6   }
                             , { 37,  0,   17       }
                             , { 3,   27            }
                             , { 37                 }
                             };

I would normally use a vector to store this but then data will be forced into ram where it doesn't fit.
I don't have much experience with large amounts of data, so is there another way to store data like this in a source file?
====================================================
EDIT:
What am I doing,
lets start by telling what a friend was doing.
A friend wants to build a theremin, he is an electronics engineer and he had problems with filtering distortions in the output signal. So I said why don't you built a digital one, when we output a pure sine wave digitally, we won't have much distortion. To make this happen we have to measure the frequency of two oscillators. The one for altering the output frequency operates between 180 and 183kHz. We haven't built the second one yet, so fixed volume for the time being.
Now he takes care of the electronic part of the project and I started programming the stm32f103c8t6.
We have already tested measuring a frequency and with the F103 at 72MHz that works fine up to 500kHz. I am using an interrupt to count periods of the input signal of 180+ kHz. In the interrupt handler I increase a uint32_t variable.
Now I have to create a sine wave of a variable frequency between 0 and 3kHz. The formula to go from 180..183kHz input to 0..3kHz output is no problem. In the main loop, I store the counter in an array[4] every 50ms and reset the counter. For the calculation I use the average of 4 measuring periods, so effectively I use the number of interrupts of the last 200ms. With the highest output frequency, I have 1000000/3000=333.3 microseconds to calculate the number of samples for the output period and the time in microseconds between the samples.
To control the resolution of the output frequency I want to set the highest number of intervals in a period and the matching time in microseconds between DAC outputs. Also I want to switch between different output frequencies exactly on the zero crossing of the output period.
So I need:

An external interrupt to measure interrupts for frequency
control

An external interrupt to measure interrupts for volume control

A timer interrupt to control output frequency.

A way to choose a number of samples and time between samples that
matches the period length closely for the correct output frequency


What did I do wrong so far:
I created too many sample sets. At first I tried with "uint8_t samples[too_many][too_many]" and flooded ram memory and after that: "const uint8_t samples[too_many][too_many]" and I flooded flash memory.
Now I have created a single sample set of 3000 values for one sine period and that looks promising. Even this set is way too big because when I write this, I realise that I cannot use 3000 samples with a 1 microsecond interrupt without using too many cpu resources. with a 3kHz signal I can do with 150 samples every 20us. But 3000*20us is a period for 16.6Hz, so that could work between 17 and 3000Hz with 3000 samples.
And again I figured out that explaining a problem to someone else is half the solution :-)

What not use samples[4][8]?

The problem is that each "line" in your array have a different length. You could work around that by making each "line" a separate array, and then have an array of pointers to them. But then you have to know exactly how many elements there is in each line (perhaps use a structure with the pointer and the size, or use a special terminator value that can't be used as a real value).

@hennep, Curious side issue, why 3.141592654 instead of a constant that is near to pi as double allows?

@Reinstate Monica, I think the final size would be: samples[988][999] Wouldn't that reserve a lot of unused space when the first line contains only 12 values? And every next line one more. I could have used 3.14 for pi as the result of the calculation will fit in an unsigned char, I just typed it as far as I know it.

Perhaps you can write all values sequentially to a 1-dimensional array and then convert the index, something like samples[convert(row, col, maxrow, maxcol)]

@hennep " Wouldn't that reserve a lot of space ...?" is unclear as you have "I could rotate the matrix by 90 degrees clockwise, but for readability I prefer not to do that." and that has the same space, yet you report as acceptable.

@pmg Sounds like a promising approach.

@hennep, since it sounds like space is an issue, consider appending a use case to allow all to help you at a more general level.

Do you actually have a double precision FPU in that STM32 or did you just pick the wrong type?

@Lundin, I have no idea what kind of FPU is in the controller but I generate the samples on my PC and include the generated source file in the STM32Cube project.

samples[988][999] generates an error as expected:
"...elf section .rodata' will not fit in region FLASH',
region `FLASH' overflowed by 957976 bytes"
samples[164][175] does fit, but will leave less space for my program. I will investigate a bit more to see how much samples I really need

Consider using sinf() instead of sin() if you're only taking 8 bits of precision anyway. Use malloc for large memory allocations. The amount of empty space is not more than a half of a 'rectangular' allocation, so might not be worth the effort of trying anything fancy.

By 'flash memory', do you mean storage? If so, you need to write to a file etc.

@hennep Bad idea since your PC has a double precision FPU but your STM32 very likely got a single precision FPU at best (or none at all, in which case this is all wrong). If your code uses floating point formats not supported by the hardware, then a software floating point library will get silently linked in, making the code vastly inefficient. Microcontroller != PC.

What STM32 is it, more specifically? Better be a Cortex M4 or bigger or you picked the wrong MCU/wrote the wrong code.

Write your data as a 1d array. The offset is the nth triangle number (whatever first dimension array index you would have used), less the firstth triangle number, plus the 2nd dimension index.

Also... "Because internal ram is limited I need to force the table into flash memory."  Every constant you place in RAM is fetched from flash. So they are already in flash and you made a RAM copy to mirror it.

"I could rotate the matrix by 90 degrees clockwise, but for readability I prefer not to do that" To me "readability" wouldn't be the main argument. Two more important things would be: 1) Bad cache usage 2) A lot of wasted memory

Quote: "The variables "first" and "last" have low values for the example but will eventually result in hundreds of sample lines." What are realistic values? Lets's say realistic values are first = 1000 and last = 1200 (i.e. 200 sample lines) then a simple 2D array like const uint8_t samples[last-first][last] won't have much overhead compared to the number of "real" values

BTW: Your question talks about "problems with RAM size" but there is no mentioning of "problems with flash size". It flash size also part of the problem?

At the moment I am working with a single array of 3000 samples. The program is using 60% of flash and 33% of ram. I will divide 3000 by the number of samples I need and step through the array. I think that will work.

If you really want to save memory, how about one long samples with getter?
const uint8_t samples[] = { 127, 248, 202, 52, 6
                           , 127, 237, 237, 127, 17, 17
                           , 127, 227, 251, 182, 72, 3, 27
                           , 127, 217, 255, 217, 127, 37, 0, 37
                           };
uint8_t get_sample(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
   // arithmetic series sum, first row length is 5 =
   // = n/2 * (2a + (n-1)d) = x*(2*5+x-1)/2=x*(9+x)/2
   unsigned arithmetic_sum = x * (9 + x) / 2;
   return samples[ arithmetic_sum + y ];
}


How about this:
const int *arr[] = {   (int[]) {1, 2},   (int[]) {2, 3, 4},   (int[]) {3, 4, 5, 6}, };

Hi @Cosinus what about it? It is exactly same as the other answer by O_____, but uses compound literals. Compared to my presented solution, will use more memory, as it needs memory for int pointers.

what if first is 1?

@KamilCuk, Your solution might use less memory, but it needs an extra multiplication. And the compiler is more flexible, it can put the data into different discontinuous backs.

Hi, @0___________ I do not follow. what if first is 1? Then it will be arithmetic_sum = x * (1 + x) / 2;

hi @Cosinus "Might" or might not. At this point, a comparison of assembly code would be nice. I am too busy to do it, but I urge you to check it on godbolt . OP is targeting stm32, so most probably arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler. Even so, that's one mult, add, shift and add. Shortly looking at assembly, get_sample has 7 instructions, that's only 1 instruction less compared to indexing, it will be as fast. https://godbolt.org/z/sz3jeYhGT

If you do not want to waste space use array of pointers:
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = stdout; // fopen("/home/hennep/arrays.c","w+");
    const int first=3, last=15;
    for( int j = first; j <= last; j++ ) 
    {
        fprintf( fp, "static const uint8_t samples%d[] = {", j, last-first+1 );
        for( int i = 0; i < j; i++ ) 
        {
            uint8_t byt = sin( 3.141592654 * 360.0 * i / j / 180.0 ) * 127.5 + 127.5;
            fprintf( fp, "%d, ", byt );
        }
        fprintf( fp, " };\n" );
    }
    fprintf( fp, "const uint8_t * const samples[] = {\n" );
    for( int j = first; j <= last; j++ ) 
    {
        fprintf( fp, "\tsamples%d, \n", j);
    }
    fprintf( fp, "\t}; \n");
}

And it will generate:
static const uint8_t samples3[] = {127, 237, 17,  };
static const uint8_t samples4[] = {127, 255, 127, 0,  };
static const uint8_t samples5[] = {127, 248, 202, 52, 6,  };
static const uint8_t samples6[] = {127, 237, 237, 127, 17, 17,  };
static const uint8_t samples7[] = {127, 227, 251, 182, 72, 3, 27,  };
static const uint8_t samples8[] = {127, 217, 255, 217, 127, 37, 0, 37,  };
static const uint8_t samples9[] = {127, 209, 253, 237, 171, 83, 17, 1, 45,  };
static const uint8_t samples10[] = {127, 202, 248, 248, 202, 127, 52, 6, 6, 52,  };
static const uint8_t samples11[] = {127, 196, 243, 253, 223, 163, 91, 31, 1, 11, 58,  };
static const uint8_t samples12[] = {127, 191, 237, 255, 237, 191, 127, 63, 17, 0, 17, 63,  };
static const uint8_t samples13[] = {127, 186, 232, 254, 246, 212, 158, 96, 42, 8, 0, 22, 68,  };
static const uint8_t samples14[] = {127, 182, 227, 251, 251, 227, 182, 127, 72, 27, 3, 3, 27, 72,  };
static const uint8_t samples15[] = {127, 179, 222, 248, 254, 237, 202, 154, 100, 52, 17, 0, 6, 32, 75,  };
const uint8_t * const samples[] = {
    samples3, 
    samples4, 
    samples5, 
    samples6, 
    samples7, 
    samples8, 
    samples9, 
    samples10, 
    samples11, 
    samples12, 
    samples13, 
    samples14, 
    samples15, 
    }; 

This data will go to the flash memory without overhead of empty spaces
https://godbolt.org/z/r8EvofTzs
https://godbolt.org/z/Ya7YTP8nf

After I posted my question, this is one of the possibilities I have tried. To my surprise the compiler can handle the same number of samples, before it generates an error, than static const uint8_t samples[164][175]. I guess the empty spaces are removed by the optimiser.

@hennep Plain 1D arrays of uint8_t have no alignment requirements so there are no spaces. Whereas a 2D array needs to have a fixed size for both dimensions. Yet another possibility is an array of structs but that too comes with overhead. What this entire question really boils down to is: why do you need this in the first place?

@Lundin for first = 1; last = 100; size = 5550 size of array[99][99] = 9801 - almost twice smaller

@hennep empty spaces are not removed by the optimizer.

@0___________ Yeah I just realized what the OP was attempting... that that kind of "2D" array where the items aren't really of a 2D nature ain't gonna fly obviously.

A compile-time generated read-only hash table might be yet another option. But then we'd probably need to store the sizes somewhere so it doesn't really save much memory.

Note: In C you could do that:
const int *arr[] = {   (int[]) {1, 2},   (int[]) {2, 3, 4},   (int[]) {3, 4, 5, 6}, };

@Cosinus what is the benefit? ALso inside block CLs lifetime is limited to to the lifetime of enclosing block

@hennep In your comment you write: " To my surprise the compiler can handle the same number of samples, before it generates an error, than static const uint8_t samples[164][175]." Sounds strange. What error do you get?

IMO this is the best solution. When last gets higher (as OP says it will) the pointer overhead will be insignificant. I might put the samples into a packed struct to avoid compiler generated space between samples. But depending on the compiler it may not make much difference.

@4386427 What I meant to say was: the array with pointers gave an error with approximately the same number of samples as a two dimensional array with empty spaces. My comment became unreadable because I edited just before the time limit.

@hennep Okay but again. What error did it give you?

@4386427 ,  region `FLASH' overflowed by 957976 bytes

@hennep for which first and last values

We're getting to many parallel discussions in different answers. I will append text my question explaining what I am doing.
